# I am trying to connect a HTTP server using telnet but it's failing

Tags: http, networking, tcp, protocols

I am learning HTTP protocols. I have choose this site for experiment: http://www.testingmcafeesites.com/testcat_ac.html

I have blocked my firewall. Opened command prompt and gave following command:

```
telnet testingmcafeesites.com 80
```

that works, then i give this:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: testingmcafeesites.com
```

I have also tried:

```
GET / testcat_ac.html HTTP/1.1
Host: testingmcafeesites.com
```

but that also doesn't work.
returns:

```
 HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 173
Connection: close

<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>Avi Vantage/</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Send this instead:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: testingmcafeesites.com
```

```
GET /testcat_ac.html HTTP/1.1
Host: testingmcafeesites.com
```

Note the space removed between `/` and `testcat_ac.html`. And the extra empty line after the `Host` header.  An HTTP request is terminated by **2** CRLF line breaks:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1<CRLF>
Host: testingmcafeesites.com<CRLF>
<CRLF>
```

```
GET /testcat_ac.html HTTP/1.1<CRLF>
Host: testingmcafeesites.com<CRLF>
<CRLF>
```